# I want to centralize my role based authorization

Tags: authorization, blazor-server-side, user-roles

I'm adding Authorization to my Razor pages.  I started with the [Authorize] attribute with defined roles.  This worked as expected.  However, rather than putting an Authorize attribute on every page, I want to centralize it to make it easier to manage.

A little background on this.  We use AAD for authentication and I am using Microsoft Identity.  I can't just "unauthenticate" users if they don't have access because that would log them out of their identity which is used a hundred other places.

This app lives in Azure so I created Roles and assigned the necessary AAD groups to the roles.  I'm in a very large and cumbersome, international company and getting changes made to AAD is very hard and involves sacrificing a body part, so I would rather not go that route.

I have groups of pages I want to Authorize users based on their assigned roles and thought I could define this in `Program.cs`.  I have 2-3 more groups of folders I would like to manage this way as well.  I want to create a policy that included certain roles.  This policy would then be used in `AuthorizeFolder` method; it doesn't work.  No error is thrown and I can access the pages despite the fact "Goofball" is not a defined role.  I also tried adding a role name to a string array and passing that in to `AuthorizeFolder`, instead of a single string.  No difference.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BasicAccess", policy => policy.RequireRole("Goofball"));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Pages", "BasicAccess" );
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My two suggestions are:

1. Use Policies [if you aren't already doing so].  I not sure from your question.  Policies are far more flexible that Roles.
2. Use inheritance from `ComponentBase` to create base pages with the correct authorization and then inherit your pages from those.

Here's an example.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminPolicy")]
public class AdminComponentBase : ComponentBase { }
```

Comment: I included the step where I am using roles to define the policy.  Per my question, the goal is to get it away from the individual pages and apply the policy at startup.

Comment: Look at Enet's answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968494/blazor-folder-authorization-not-working-allows-non-logged-in-users-to-see-conte.

Comment: <ugh> that sounds like a step backwards.  Thanks, not sure why that didn't come up in my searches.  I've voted to close as a duplicate

Comment: Added my vote to yours. Someone else do the same.